# GMail API: Not Found (404) errors when calling retrieving drafts with drafts.get from ids supplied by drafts.list

Tags: gmail-api

In the Gmail API quite frequently drafts.list will return a draft id
but when I pass it to drafts.get it returns a 404 error. This is
repeatable for certain draft ids, I can call drafts.list again and
they're still there and I can then call drafts.get and get the same
error again. I can also call messages.get with the given message id
and get a response as expected and I can see the draft in the gmail client.

Seems to be a bug in the GMail API. Any ideas for workarounds? And does anyone know the right way to report bugs to Google?

Comment: Not exactly a solution but I found that I could get the info I was after via messages.get (drafts.list also gives message ids for each draft)

Comment: Hmm this is indeed odd.  Can you report user email and message+draft IDs at http://goo.gl/NCpJXf ?

Comment: The draft's I was getting this error on before won't be around now (will have been sent) but it was coming up really quite often before we switched to the workaround above. If I can trigger it again on my own account I'll try leave the draft in place and report the ids.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same issue, here is how to reproduce:

1) Start writing a new message in the Gmail web client. Don't add anything in the To field or the Body. Then close the message to save it as a Draft.

2) Retrieve a list of threads with the following code:

```
threads = gmail_client.users().threads().list(userId='me', maxResults=15, pageToken=pageToken, q='-in:(chats OR draft) in:all').execute()
```

4) Then retrieve each of these threads in a batch request:

```
batch.add(gmail_client.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=thread['id'], format='metadata', metadataHeaders=['subject','date','to','from']), callback=threadCallback)
```

The error that gets returned is:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/154e44a4c80ec7e4?format=metadata&metadataHeaders=subject&metadataHeaders=date&metadataHeaders=to&metadataHeaders=from&alt=json returned "Not Found">

Answer (score 0):

In order to use drafts.get, you should use immutable id of the draft, not the message id of the draft which will change after each update in draft. Drafts.list supplies both immutable id and the message id of the messages in the draft.